# How to wildcard search with capture in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a routine in C to capture sequences of characters in a string argument.  The matching criteria in addition to characters can have `?` meaning exactly one character and `*` meaning zero or more characters.  (lazy).

e.g.

string: `ok1ok1234567890`

match:  `*(ok?2*)4*`

The result should be the position of the match = 3 and the length of the match = 5

I have tried numerous ways of doing this, have put it aside, come back to it, put it aside again etc.  I cannot crack it.  It needs to be a purely C solution and able to capture multiple captures.

e.g. `(*)(ok??)3(4*)8*`

Every solution I come up with works in many cases but not all.  I'm hoping someone somewhere might have done this already or have an insight to how it can be done.

Comment: There are regular expressions libraries available for C; you would have to reformat your matching string to something like `(ok.?2.*)4` though.

Comment: There are numerous descriptions in the literature of how to write related regular expressions — I've not seen exactly that hybrid of shell notation and regular expressions before, but I've not read everything.  One such description is in [Beautiful Code](http://www.amazon.com/Beautiful-Code-Leading-Programmers-Practice/dp/0596510047).  Another is in Kernighan & Pike
[The Practice of Programming](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/tpop.webpage/).

Comment: refer regcomp and regexec function in C

Comment: I don't want to use any of the regex libraries as my requirement is specific and requires high performance.  I'm sure what I require is possible and equally sure it can be done much more efficiently than using a library function.